# Como obter diretório atual de uma aplicação web?

Tags: java

Preciso saber como eu obtenho o diretório corrente da minha aplicação, pois preciso salvar alguns arquivos PDF. Já tentei algumas vezes, mas sem sucesso. Alguém pode me dar uma luz? Olhem como estou fazendo:

```
public String salvarPDF() throws IOException {
    String nomeArquivo = FilenameUtils.getName(arquivoUploadPDF.getFileName());
    InputStream input = arquivoUploadPDF.getInputstream();
    String caminhoCompleto = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\main\\webapp\\uploads\\pdfs";
    String caminho = "uploads\\pdfs";
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File(caminhoCompleto, nomeArquivo));
    caminho += "\\" + nomeArquivo;
```

Answer (score 3):

Outra alternativa:

```
URL location = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
System.out.println(location.getFile());
```

A vantagem dessa versão é que ela também funciona com caminhos dentro de pacotes (em um `jar`, `war`, `ear`, etc).

---

**Fonte**: [SOen - Getting the Current Working Directory in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21274808/664577)

Answer (score 2):

É bem simples:

```
String caminhoApp = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
```